# Member of staff leaving and wants photos

Tags: meetings

We have 2 very popular members of staff that are leaving, and one has mentioned it would be nice to have some photo memories. Which is fine. However, the logistics of this is proving difficult. There would be up to 100 people involved across 4-5 teams.

- We thought of a group photo, but trying to get people together at one point in time will be difficult
- Then we thought maybe a photo of each team, but this could be time consuming
- Another idea was to get people to take photos on the leaving do and e-mail them to us, but I doubt they would.
- Alternatively, it was just a hint and we could completely ignore it, but it would be nice to achieve.

At the same time if we do it for one person, we would have to repeat for the other.

Has anyone else done this, or can see the most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> We thought of a group photo

Not everyone has to be in it, you could just get the day where most people will be in and take the photo. If people are that bothered about being in the photo then I'm sure they'll find a way to be in it.

> maybe a photo of each team

How is this time consuming? A photo takes a minute or so, you have 5 teams, therefore using only 5 minutes?

I personally don't see a huge problem with either approach, slight inconvenience maybe. However, both are very achievable and effective to achieve your goal.

Another alternative could be to hire a professional for the leaving do and just get the company/individual to send you the photos.

Comment: If the teams are on a rotation or work shifts over 24 hours, when will they be in together? OP made it clear that the "logistics were proving difficult"...

Comment: We all work 9ish to 5ish but are constantly out of the office, arranged or urgently.

Comment: Naz, Confer with the two leaving and select three or four time-slots for taking photos at slightly different locations, then email blast those time-slots to everyone. The results won't be perfect, but they should do. Also, if someone straggles in one or two minutes late, just have that person take a picture with the people leaving. It can be a mix of different pictures. Some pictures will have 30 people in them. Some will have 10. And some pictures may only contain 2 or 3 people. It's all fine (as long as the people leaving are there).

Answer (score 3):

This is an idea for a different approach, trying to get round the "logistic issues" the OP mentions.

Create a shared directory and ask all of them to do their own "selfie" and post it there.

That way it is optional for those that don't want to and, at the same time, "creative" for those who do.

Comment: How does this gather the memory setting that they're trying to achieve

Comment: @Twyxz Can you force people to be part of a photo? Should you force them? And as for "memory", some could do a selfie by the coffee machine, others by the printer - waiting for the printer can be a common thing... etc etc etc

Comment: They don't have to be part of the photo if they don't want to? They can simply just walk away from it. But getting a group of everyone who is willing is much more sentimental than a selfie. I'm sure most members of staff have selfies on facebook you can look at if you wanted selfies.

Comment: the individual selfies can be gathered together in a collage arrangement. Maybe there will be an official shaking-hands with a manager ceremony which will form the centrepiece then individuals can be arranged round the edge and it's printed poster-sized.

Answer (score 3):

We've done this with projects I've been on in the past by arranging a group get together - either a shared lunch (paid for by the project) or drinks after work, and taking the photo then.

The subsidised lunch version gets much higher attendance, since it doesn't interfere with people's out of work commitments.